# R split data into 2 parts randomly

Tags: r, random, split

I am trying to split my data frame into 2 parts randomly. For example, I'd like to get a random 70% of the data into one data frame and the other 30% into other data frame. Is there a fast way to do this? The number of rows in the original data frame is over 800000. I've tried with a for loop, selecting a random number from the number of rows, and then binding that row to the first (70%) data frame using rbind() and deleting it from the original data frame to get the other (30%) data frame. But this is extremely slow. Is there a relatively fast way I could do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(x=runif(n), y=rnorm(n))
ind <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
data1 <- data[ind, ]
data2 <- data[!ind, ]
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Works quickly when extended to 800K cases too.

Comment: Works really fast. Even when I repeat it in a loop multiple times. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I am building on the answer by ExperimenteR, which appears robust. One issue however is that the `sample` function is a bit weird in that it uses probabilities, which are not completely deterministic. Take this for example:

```
>sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
```

You would expect that the number of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values to be exactly 70 and 30, respectively. Oftentimes, this is not the case:

```
>table(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3)))

 FALSE  TRUE 
    34    66
```

Which is alright if you're not looking to be super precise. But if you would like *exactly* 70% and 30%, then do this instead:

```
v <- as.vector(c(rep(TRUE,70),rep(FALSE,30))) #create 70 TRUE, 30 FALSE
ind <- sample(v) #Sample them randomly. 
data1 <- data[ind, ] 
data2 <- data[!ind, ]
```

Comment: Try `ind <- sample(c(rep(TRUE,ceiling(nrow(data)*0.7)),rep(FALSE,floor(nrow(data)*0.3))))`

Comment: Partially true yes, ultimately needs numbers that are factors or multiple of 100. Yours is more robust, +1.

Comment: sorry meant to say my method ultimately needs numbers that are multiples of 10.